# Using ScrollView

Tags: android, scrollview, android-relativelayout

I try to implement following behavior of my app:
I've got list of views and show them in scrollview partly.
If user scroll and reaches bottom of scrollview, I add one more view below last view;
If user scroll up and reaches top of scrollview, I add view above the first view.

My problem is that when I add view above the first view it shift all views in layout down.
[image]

My question is: how to add view above view in hidden area, so user could have a look  by scrolling up?

Comment: Use view's visibility="GONE" at first,and onScroll listener set view's visibility="VISIBLE".

Comment: Are you using `ScrollView` or `ListView`?

Comment: Giru Bhai, I need the first view

Comment: It almost sounds like your after a "pull down to refresh" effect.  If so, take a look here: http://www.tutecentral.com/android-pull-to-refresh